# Microsoft Outlook: Add senders to contacts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, contacts

We're using Microsoft Outlook 2003/2007 with NON-EXHCANGE mailboxes, stored in PST files.
Is there a way to quickly add a large number of senders from the inbox to the users contact list?

I was thinking to export all the senders from the inbox in the PST file to a list and then so use scripting to add them all to the contact list, or perhaps arrange in CSV and import.

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Contact group in the Contacts tab, add it to recipients or export it as well.